# Frequently insert and delete elements using std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a game which could have a **million** "boxes". For convenience, I use `std::vector<shared_ptr<Boxes>>` to save them. But today, I want to break some "box" if the box is subjected to a certain impact, so I have to split the box into "**two** small boxes".

Here is the question - in the game, there are so many "boxes" that would break which involves the `std::vector` insert (new small boxes generated) and delete (old boxes split). And each "box" contains many information like mass, shape, volume, and so on. So, I have no idea about enhancing performance of the `std::vector` for frequent inserts and deletes. And it is difficult for me to change to another data structure that I have to keep using `std::vector`.

I had read some efficient trick to use `std::vector` like: use `reserve()` before inserting elements to avoid reallocating memory, or maybe move semantic can be used here?

Comment: For something like this vector isn't the best container. If you want a "random access"-like container then `std::deque` perhaps. Otherwise `std::list` is a good container for frequent deletions and insertions.

Comment: `std::vector<shared_ptr<Boxes>>` you are only moving around shared pointers not reallocating the Boxes

Comment: Maybe you realize this already, but you mentioned what each box is containing so I am not sure. You are not storing boxes in your vector, you are storing shared pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That advice is fine if insertion and deletion are the *only* operations.  But in a game engine, OP is almost certainly iterating over all elements of the container, and in that case `std::deque` and `std::list` are both awful for performance because the elements are not contiguous in memory, resulting in cache misses that will dominate all other performance factors.  Though to be fair, OP is already wrapping all `Boxes` in `shared_ptr`, so cache coherency is already out the window.

Comment: Do you actually need to insert anywhere but the end of the vector? Because insertions at the end are pretty quick generally speaking. In general it doesn't sound like you'd need to preserve order, so for removal you can also just swap the element to be removed with the last one (and then only remove the last element)

Comment: @0x5453 Copying "million" of "boxes" is still going to be a major factor. And that happens each time a new "box" is inserted in the middle of the vector. Copying pointers is cheaper than large objects, true, but it's still copying possibly millions of objects. And it will probably be quite a few cache misses for that as well.

Comment: You can avoid deleting entries anyway by reusing the shared pointer already present in the vector / whatever container you end up using and just insert a new one pointing to the other box you create.

Comment: To the OP: Implement using vector, list and deque. Then *benchmark*. Use the one that is best for your use-case.

Comment: Why *shared pointer*?  Why not just `vector<Box>`?

Comment: Sorry for my inclear quesion description, i haven't notice that share_ptr is save in to the std::vector but not "box" itself. So it would cost less time to move shared_ptr but "box"?And then my order is not valuable to this situation.

Comment: @jaybosco -- As already mentioned, implement the code and benchmark it by running an optimized build of your code.  You are making assumptions about speed that you have not proven yet.  OK, let's say it is millions, but you find out that the performance is lightning fast.  Instead of wasting time with [analysis paralysis](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/analysisparalysis.asp#:~:text=our%20editorial%20policies-,What%20Is%20Analysis%20Paralysis%3F,an%20inability%20to%20pick%20one.), you would get on with writing the rest of the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from an empty data structure:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Box>> boxes;
```

We can reserve capacity for 2 million boxes. This is probably too much, but allows for each box to be split once:

```
boxes.reserve(2_000_000);
```

Now, at the start of the game you can use `push_back` to fill up this vector.

At some later point, you decide you want to break a box in two.
You can *replace* the original box with one of the fragments, and push_back the other one:

```
void breakBox(int i) {
  std::shared_ptr<Box> fragment1 = ...; // something that reads from boxes[i]
  std::shared_ptr<Box> fragment2 = ...; // something that reads from boxes[i]
  boxes[i] = fragment1;
  boxes.push_back(fragment2);
}
```

Simply adding boxes is still O(1) as long as you stay under the 2M boundary. Otherwise you incur a copy of the full `boxes` vector and then you are good for quite a while again.

Finally, should you ever want to remove a box, you can use a trick mentioned in the comments: swap it with the last box and then free the last box. This is O(1).

```
void deleteBox(int i) {
  std::swap(boxes[i], boxes.back());
  boxes.pop_back();
}
```